# How to monitor a remote read-only subversion repo for commit changes and do "svn update" immediately?

Tags: svn

I want to enable monitoring of remote read-only subversion for commit changes and do "svn update" immediately. How i can do this ?

Maybe some script with wget of svn log page, cut(grep) everything except first line with revision, compare number with local copy(is there an svn command that will display local rev number?) and it it is not equal then run "svn update" and set this script to run every minute ?

SVN: http://code.google.com/p/miranda/source/list

Comment: Is server replication an option you can use? Like using `svnsync` or write-through proxying?

Comment: No, I dont' have direct access to the remote repository.

Comment: Why don't you just schedule an `svn update` command to be run every minute? IMHO, you don't need to monitor remote repo: if there were no changes, the update command will just do nothing...

Comment: You right, but if i have the compare method, i can also do some other things, not only svn update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
#! /bin/bash

REMOTE_REPO="http://miranda.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/"
LOCAL_REPO="/lib/svn/miranda/"

REMOTE_REV=`svn info $REMOTE_REPO | grep '^Revision:' | awk '{print $2}'`
LOCAL_REV=`svn info $LOCAL_REPO | grep '^Revision:' | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ $REMOTE_REV -eq $LOCAL_REV ]; then
exit 0;
else
# Run your commands here.
cd $LOCAL_REPO
svn up
fi
```